# Using TexShop, upgraded to OS X El Capitan, and the fix isn't working

Tags: errors, mactex, texshop, mac

I am having issues compiling in TeXShop since upgrading to El Capitan.  I have searched extensively for a fix, but none of the recommended settings are fixing my problem.  Here is a screenshot of my settings in TeXShop:

[image]

These settings produce the error: "/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex does not exist. TeXShop is  a front end for TeX, but you also need a TeX distribution. Perhaps such a distribution was not installed or was removed during a system upgrade. If so, go to http://www.tug.org/mactex/ and follow the instructions to (re)install MacTeX. A less likely possibility is that a tool path is incorrectly configured in TeXShop preferences. This can happen if you are using the macports or fink distributions."

Additionally, I already tried reinstalling MacTex to no effect.  TeXShop is fully updated.

---

I tried compiled from the command line the simple document (named practice.tex):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Hi
\end{document}
```

I tried
`/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/*/pdflatex practice.tex` and got:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded >format=pdflatex)
>   restricted \write18 enabled.
>   entering extended mode
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex
>   LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
>   Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
>
> ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help.
>   ...
>
> l.1 ?

I then tried `pdflatex practice.tex` and got "command not found."

`echo $PATH` returns:

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-darwin

`kpsewhich -var TEXMFMAIN` returns "command not found."

`which pdflatex` returns nothing.

---

`ls -l /Library/TeX/texbin` gives

> total 8
>   lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  29 Nov 29 21:48 texbin -> Distributions/Programs/texbin

`ls /usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/` gives:

> universal-darwin   x86_64-darwin

Comment: You ought not need to change the settings if TeX Shop is updated. Are you using MacTeX 2015? You need the 2015 version of TeX Live. Earlier editions will not work. Please try compiling from the command line to see if that works. Try both `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/*/pdflatex <tex file>` and `pdflatex <tex file>` to make sure it works in both cases. `echo $PATH` would be useful, as would `kpsewhich -var TEXMFMAIN` and `which pdflatex`.

Comment: I tried typing in the things you suggest.  I use command lines virtually never, so I put exactly what I did above, in case I did something incorrectly.  The results are above.

Comment: Interesting. What does `ls -l /Library/TeX/texbin` give? And what does `ls /usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/` give?

Comment: Put those in.  See above.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry - I haven't used OS X for a while. Somebody on a Mac as they tried to help would be quicker as they wouldn't have to ask these questions :(.

Comment: What about `ls -l /Library/TeX/Distributions/Programs/texbin`? If it has an `->` in it, try `ls -l /Library/TeX/Distributions/Programs/<whatever is after the arrow>` until you get something without an arrow. And `ls -l /usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/`? (I didn't realise you'd have 2 things here - I only have one, but I'm on Linux.)

Comment: I decided to wipe as much of mactex off my computer as possible and try another install of the current version.  Worked this time.  Thanks for the assistance, though!

Answer (score 1):

In the end, a complete uninstall of MacTex worked.  I followed the instructions here: https://tug.org/mactex/uninstalling.html, then reinstalled MacTex-2015.  Everything compiles like it should.