# TeXShop compilation issue on Mac OS El Capitan. Complete uninstallation and re-installation did not fix the problem

Tags: errors, mactex, texshop, mac

I am a basic user and sorry if I miss to state some important facts.

I have similar problem raised [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280705/using-texshop-upgraded-to-os-x-el-capitan-and-the-fix-isnt-working?rq=1) and also in many other pages.
First, I followed the guides by Herbert Schulz, didn't work for me.

Afterwards, completely uninstalled MacTex with all GUI Applications and distribution files, then re-installed MacTex. Still, didn't work.

I also updated TexShop and BibDesk, which are the softwares I use.

Moreover, run the Setup-2015 package at Applications/TeX folder.

However, still when I click to typeset, TexShop brings the following message:

> /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex/simpdftex does not exist. TeXShop is  a front end for TeX, but you also need a TeX distribution. Perhaps such a distribution was not installed or was removed during a system upgrade. If so, go to http : // tug . org / MacTeX and follow the instructions to (re)install MacTeX. A less likely possibility is that a tool path is incorrectly configured in TeXShop preferences. This can happen if you are using the macports or fink distributions.

This is how my TexShop Preference looks like:[image: TexShop Preferences]

Comment: First of, what is simpdftex?

Comment: @daleif It's part of the TeXLive distribution. It does latex+dvips+ps2pdf in one shot.

Comment: Never heard of it before. Is the OP actually sure it is included in mactex? Can it be found via the comnand line?

Comment: The problem is that in your Path settings (the first box in your settings image) you have put `/Library/TeX/texbin/pdftex` but this is incorrect. It should be simply `/Library/TeX/texbin`

Comment: @daleif Yes, it's part of TeXLive and therefore part of MacTeX. The issue doesn't have anything to do with this script.

Comment: @AlanMunn I see that now

Comment: Compiling issue is solved indeed by following @AlanMunn suggestion. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with how you specified the path in the preferences.  The correct path is `/Library/TeX/texbin` not `Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex` (which is not a directory path, but the actual `pdflatex` program itself. The error you got showed this since it said `/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex/simpdftex does not exist.` The presence of `pdflatex` in the path is the source of the problem.